# Does dynamic_cast check the type_info object of the queried object, or recursively?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, vtable, dynamic-cast, typeinfo

I have been reading around how `dynamic_cast` works and from what I gathered so far, it obtains the object, gets the vptr, goes to the vtable and in the -1 or 0th element, there is a pointer to a `type_info` object. However, from this point on it gets a little hazy:

Does the `type_info` object contain all data necessary to (possibly) do the cast, or does the runtime system need to access other type_info objects?

I am trying to understand how many different objects/vtables and type_info objects are accessed whilst checking an inheritance hierarchy during `dynamic_cast`.

EDIT: Compiler-wise MSVC or GCC

Comment: You should precise the compiler (visual studio i guess) as it is compiler specific. Also use pointers in your sample code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unspecified, and depends on the implementation, but the
information relative to converting a pointer to another type in
the hierarchy, at least when virtual inheritance is involved,
depend on the actual most derived class; having found that the
class is a `D`, information from `B` or `C` would *not* help
finding the actual address of `A` in the `D`.  The position of
the `A` part in the object will differ depending on the most
derived class.  To see this clearly, create classes with a data
member, and display the different addresses:

```
struct B
{
    int b;
    B() : b( 1 ) {}
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct L : virtual public B
{
    int l;
    L() : l( 2 ) {}
};

struct R : virtual public B
{
    int r;
    R() : r( 3 ) {}
};

struct D: public L, public R
{
    int d;
    D() : d( 4 ) {}
};

struct E : public D
{
    int e;
    E() : e( 5 ) {}
};

template <typename T>
class HexDump
{
    T const& myObj;
public:
    HexDump( T const& obj ) : myObj( obj ) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, HexDump const& obj )
    {
        dest.fill( '0' );
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield );
        uint32_t const* p = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t const*>( &obj.myObj );
        for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(T) / sizeof(uint32_t); ++ i ) {
            if ( i != 0 ) {
                dest << ' ';
            }
            dest << std::setw( sizeof(uint32_t) * 2 ) << p[i];
        }
        return dest;
    }
};

template <typename T>
HexDump<T>
hexDump( T const& obj )
{
    return HexDump<T>( obj );
}

int
addrDiff( void const* lhs, void const* rhs )
{
    return static_cast<char const*>( lhs ) - static_cast<char const*>( rhs );
}

int
main()
{
    B* aD = new D;
    B* anE = new E;
    std::cout << "position of B in D: " << addrDiff( aD, dynamic_cast<D*>( aD ) ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "position of B in E: " << addrDiff( anE, dynamic_cast<E*>( anE ) ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "D: " << hexDump( *dynamic_cast<D*>( aD ) ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "E: " << hexDump( *dynamic_cast<E*>( anE ) ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The initialization of the various data elements allow you to see
the position of the different classes (or their payloads)
clearly.

Note in particular that the vptr of the `B` sub-object is different in a `D` and in a `B`; the RTTI infos in the vtbl it points to must reflect the most derived class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you are saying :) I understand (roughly) how objects are represented in memory for basic inheritance (they just follow their base classes in memory). However, when a dynamic_cast is performed it needs to check whether the types are in fact related? To do this, it accesses the type_info object. So my question was does the type_info object contain all classes that object derives from, or does it only contain the immediate-base classes and then you have to obtain their type_infos to continue up the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: @mezamorphic It needs more than just the info as to whether the classes are related; it needs information as to how to modify the pointer to the object.  And this information will be different in each class.  So the type info for `D` and `E` must contain the relevant info for `B`; the implementation can't go through `L` or `R` to find it, because the information would be different.

Comment: My question kind of follows on from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359780/how-is-dynamic-cast-implemented

Comment: James, but the compiler knows which classes are related at compile time. So for a very naïve approach why can't the compiler just list all the base classes, in each type_info object, for each polymorphic type? In my simplistic example the type_info of D would say {L, R, B}. I understand you say it would need to do more work to do the actual cast, but surely ascertaining whether it can do the cast just requires knowing the base classes? I must be missing something as this doesn't seem difficult?

Comment: To further my example, if we had "class A", "class B : public A" and "class C : public B" we know the type info for B would be {A,B} (assuming B can dynamic_cast itself?), and type_info for C would be {A, B, C}. I do not know as much about multiple or virtual inheritance, so perhaps this is why I am not fully understanding you.

Comment: @mezamorphic The only time you need to determine whether you can do the actual cast is when you are trying to do the cast.  The information in the base classes does not allow you to do the cast, so it must be present in the most derived class.  Some sort of dynamic look up is used to find the information, in the type infos of the derived class; if this fails, then you can't do the cast; if it succeeds, you use the information to do the cast.

Comment: @mezamorphic For simple, direct inheritance, there will normally be only one vtable (once the object is fully constructed); the vtable for the most derived class (which will subsume the vtables for the base classes).  Once multiple inheritance comes into play, it becomes more complicated, _but_ the type info is always that of the most derived class, which contains the various informations necessary for the conversion of pointers in `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58340/discussion-between-mezamorphic-and-james-kanze).

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting my question (possibly). I know the check needs to be done at run-time. My question is whether the compiler can populate an object's type_info object with a list of ALL the classes which that object may legally be dynamically casted to, so that only one type info object needs to be checked. If this wasn't the case, would the run-time system have to obtain a type_info object for one class and use that to obtain the type_info object for another class, etc until it has determined whether the cast can be performed (not HOW it is performed, just IF).

Comment: I am just trying to ask if the type_info object contains exhaustive information for whether the object can be casted (and therefore no other type_info objects need to be checked), or whether type_info objects for each class in the hierarchy need to be checked recursively?

Comment: I think I addressed that.  Not only can the compiler populate an object's type info with _all_ of the classes involved in the inheritance hierarchy, it _must_.  No other implementation works.

Comment: So only one vtable look-up and type_info retrieval is done during dynamic_cast and this is for the object passed in to the cast?

Comment: @mezamorphic The type info that the code gets is the one which corresponds to the most derived class pointed to.  No others are necessary.